# Paypal the underlying connection was closed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal

I am trying to get the response from paypal sandbox environment to test the variables coming back from paypal. I am using asp.net and vb.net now the code works fine on the live paypal url but not on the local one for some strange reason.

I want to use the sandbox environment for local testing but I am presented with the following error.

> An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Now the code works live on

```
 Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"), HttpWebRequest)
```

I had assumed that all I change was this

```
  Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"),
```

Main Code

```
 Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"), HttpWebRequest)
    'Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim Param() As Byte = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength)
    Dim strRequest As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param)
    strRequest = strRequest + "&cmd=_notify-validate"
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length

    'Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    Dim streamOut As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
    streamOut.Write(strRequest)
    streamOut.Close()
    Dim streamIn As StreamReader = New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim strResponse As String = streamIn.ReadToEnd()
    streamIn.Close()

    'Assign payment variables 
    strOrderNo = HttpContext.Current.Request("item_number")
    strGross = HttpContext.Current.Request("mc_gross")
```

**Edit 2**
After further investigations it appears to be the way paypal changed their sandbox but I cannot upgrade my application to 4.5 to just use sandbox is their any option open to me?. As per this stack

[Using PayPal PDT with vb.net and getting: the underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106856/using-paypal-pdt-with-vb-net-and-getting-the-underlying-connection-was-closed)

Which suggests to change this line to use Tsl12 but that is not an option in my web site and I cannot upgrade it as its a daily used site at moment.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Why is it the code work fine in the live environment why has paypal changed their sandbox to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling I found how to fix this using the following hack

```
Const _Tls12 As SslProtocols = DirectCast(&HC00, SslProtocols)
Const Tls12 As SecurityProtocolType = DirectCast(_Tls12, SecurityProtocolType)
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12
```

Thanks to this great op at [How to implement Security Protocols TLS 1.2 in .Net 3.5 framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484888/how-to-implement-security-protocols-tls-1-2-in-net-3-5-framework/44893192#44893192)

Can anyone let me no the implications of using the above hack will it be future proof.